# Is it possible to do a subquery on a column SELECT:ed from information_schema?

Tags: mysql

Take a look at the following query (its not working becuase templates.a.COLUMN_NAME does not exist).

```
SELECT a.COLUMN_NAME, a.COLUMN_COMMENT, (SELECT templates.a.COLUMN_NAME AS status FROM templates WHERE ID=5)    FROM information_schema.COLUMNS AS a WHERE a.TABLE_NAME = 'templates' AND column_name LIKE 'rev%';
```

I want to SELECT the data in the column that corresponds to the COLUMN_NAME (where ID=5)  that was selected from information_schema. Is this possible to do? Maybe I am trying to do it reverse?

I am looking for a result like this:

```
COLUMN_NAME      COLUMN_COMMENT           status
rev_body_easy    Body text easy to read   2
rev_header_easy  Header easy to read      1
```

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot dynamically select column names like that in a MySQL query :/.

Comment: I read somewhere that it might be possible by having the information_schema build the entire query for you and execute it as Dynamic SQL. Do you have any idea how that works?

Comment: You want prepared statements http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html

Comment: @ogc-nick: *fortunately* it's not possible :)